# Horospherical distance in CAT($-1$) space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, non-positive-curvature

In $\mathbb{H}^n$, equipped with its hyperbolic metric of constant curvature $-1$, if we have two points $p,q$ on a common horosphere $\partial S$, then $$d_{\mathbb{H}}(p,q) = 2\sinh^{-1} (d_{\partial S} (p,q)/2)$$ where $d_{\partial S}(p,q)$ is the shortest path from $p$ to $q$ that lies on the horosphere.

Is there any version of this identity in a general $CAT(-1)$ metric space? I must admit my hyperbolic trigonometry is very weak.

Comment: In the Riemannian case with curvature $\le -1$ one should not expect more than an inequality $\sinh(d/2)\le d_{\partial S}/2$, and hence also in the CAT($-1$) case. For instance in a tree the horospheres are totally disconnected, so the right-hand term is infinite.

Comment: do you have a source for the inequality you've just stated?

Comment: No, I don't even know if it holds, it's just intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I'll answer my own question.

According to this paper: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214434219
if $M$ is a Hadamard manifold with pinched sectional curvature $-b^2\leq K \leq -a^2$, and if $H$ is a horosphere and $h$ represents distance in $H$, then $$\frac{2}{a}\sinh (a/2) d(p,q)\leq h(p,q) \leq \frac{2}{b}\sinh (b/2) d(p,q)$$ with the obvious modifications if $a=0$, $b=-\infty$. As mentioned in the comments, a general inequality for a $CAT(-1)$ space seems to be asking for too much.

Comment: Well, one direction seems plausible in the CAT($-1$) setting (which generalizes curvature $-\infty\le\kappa\le -1$)